# Rest of divs are shown when resizing browser in single page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a single page website, the page is composed by a header and a footer, both fixed at top and bottom respectively and the content in the middle.
The content is a div with 100% of width and height.

At the header there is a menu to access the sections with smooth scrolling, everything works fine at this point, but when I choose the third section and resize the browser I can see the divs above and below, which should be hidden.

I tried to position the current div absolute with addClass/removeClass and modify the height when resize but did not work either.

This is the code:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #cabecera, #footer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #D1D1D1;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        #cabecera {
            top: 0;
        }

        #footer {
            bottom: 0;
        }

        #menu li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        #menu li span {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .centrar {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #section1 {
            background-color: #fbfbfb;
        }

        #section2 {
            background-color: #017EFF;
        }

        #section3 {
            background-color: #9F25F6;
        }

        #section4 {
            background-color: #FB8114;
        }

        #section5 {
            background-color: #373737;
        }

        .layout {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .active {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var target = this.hash;
                var $target = $(target);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                }, 900, 'swing');

                /*$("#section1").removeClass("active");
                $("#section2").removeClass("active");
                $("#section3").removeClass("active");
                $("#section4").removeClass("active");
                $("#section5").removeClass("active");*/

                /*$target.addClass("active");*/
            });


            /*$(window).resize(function () {
                var doc = $(document).height() || $(window).height();

                var cabecera = $("#cabecera").height();
                var footer = $("#footer").height();

                var margin = doc - cabecera - footer;
                $('#section3').css({ 'min-height': + margin + 'px' });
            });

            $(window).resize();*/
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="cabecera">
        <div class="centrar">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#section1" target="_self">section1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section2" target="_self">section2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3" target="_self">section3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section4" target="_self">section4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section5" target="_self">section5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="section1" class="layout"></div>
    <div id="section2" class="layout"></div>
    <div id="section3" class="layout"></div>
    <div id="section4" class="layout"></div>
    <div id="section5" class="layout"></div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="centrar"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**
[Screenshot normal browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFb29.jpg) // 
[Screenshot resized browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsSmz.jpg)

Steps to reproduce:
1) Open the browser resized to a small window
2) Open the page
3) Go to "section3"
4) Change the height of the browser, increasing or decrementing
5) Take a look at the divs above and below :S

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your error with your code. Which browser did you test this in? In case of doubt, add a screenshot?

Comment: It happens in chrome, firefox, ie,... You are right, a screenshot will demonstrate the problem better, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scroll to the top of the selected element(initialized on first) on the resize event of the window without any animation so that it gets executed transparently for the visitor.

The $target variable needs to be declared "globally" so that the resize function will know which was the last accessed section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $target = $(".layout:first");
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var target = this.hash;
                $target = $(target);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                }, 900, 'swing');

            });
            $(window).resize(function(){
                $(window).scrollTop($target.offset().top);
            });
        });
    </script>
```